# rounded rectangle mask created for small squares using imagemagick is not correct

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am creating a rounded rectangle mask using

```
convert -size 256x256 xc:none -draw "roundrectangle 0,0,256,256,47,47" mask.png
```

This works fine. However using the same command for `16x16` as follows

```
 convert -size 16x16 xc:none -draw "roundrectangle 0,0,16,16,3,3" mask.png
```

produces a mask.png in which the rounded corners don't look correct. Infact top left corner looks ok and bottom right corner looks distorted.

My convert version is

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-6 Q16 i586 2014-09-06 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

For each image the rounded radius is 47/256 ~= 3/16 ~= 18%

Am I not running the commands correct or are these artifacts expected? Could this be imagemagick limitation.

My final aim is to use this mask and composite it to make an application icon for various sizes ranging from 16x16 all the way to 1024x1024. Since the mask is created wrong so are the final icons when compositing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more related to a basic canvas overflow. Just remember that an array of pixels starts at `0` and ends at `n-1` *(where `n` is the size of the array.)*

[image: array index]

If you draw on an image with the size `16x16`, the first pixel will have a access coordinate of `0,0` and a the last pixel at `15,15`. This is the same with your first example, but the image & curve is large enough not to notice the last pixel is trimmed off.

```
convert -size 16x16 xc:none -draw "roundrectangle 0,0,15,15,3,3" mask.png
```

Comment: Great, I feel a little dumb now :) Thanks this does solve the problem. The mask is now perfect